# Unreal Engine : Why use subobject when creating Actor?

Tags: actor, unreal-engine4, subobject

RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject(TEXT("RootComponent"));

I want to know the reason why we make subobject here.

I used a translator because I couldn't speak English well.

Thank You.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand you do not speak English, but this question does not have enough details for us to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This function creates a component inside your object. Objects are instances of your class. The result is the same as clicking the component button in the blueprint editor.